# why vscode wants to run python scripts with gcc?

Tags: python, gcc, visual-studio-code

i decided to learn C. I did set up vscode to start writing C programs. I installed Mingw and gcc.
when I went back to one of my older python projects vscode wants to run it with gcc and i tried closing-reopening it .
Can someone help me solve this problem? Also I'm not sure if this is the right place but I didn't find a better place in all sites in stack exchange.

Comment: Can you show us the exact message that VSCode is giving you?

Comment: you have to select a different launch configuration

Comment: @rioV8 i don't know how

Comment: @C.Nivs https://ibb.co/N1svNHt

Comment: have you read the VSC doc pages about debugging, and the specific pages for C++ and Python

Comment: i'm a 9 yo why is it so hard god dammit

Comment: Enough information to reproduce the problem and test proposed answers should be included **in the question itself**. See [mre] guidelines.

Comment: Re: "why is it so hard?" -- that's a longer philosophical question, but my general take comes down to the [law of leaky abstractions](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/). You've got 50 years of people building new layers to "simplify" things on top of older layers, but the older layers are still there, and when the new layers break you need to know the old layers to understand why. It's a lot to learn -- especially to understand the rationale behind every component -- and that takes time.

Comment: (also, that essay is almost 20 years old, and so there are even more abstractions on top of the ones that existed back when it was written; it just keeps getting harder and harder if you want to really understand _why_ everything works the way it does).

Comment: i just wanted to be cool and use vscode instead of thony who's as advanced and future rich as note pad

Answer (score 1):

Do you have this line in your launch.json file?

```
"preLaunchTask": "Task",
```

You need to annotate this line.